# JQuery UI Dialog Slow to Load in IE8 (Loads quickly the first time)

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I know IE javascript performance is abysmal compared to FF and Chrome, but most of my users us IE8. I don't notice the performance problem in FF (surprise). I am using Jquery and Jquery-ui for the dialog functionality.

Basically, I have a large number of links that I load into a dialog box using ajax. The first time I click the button to bring up the dialog box it loads very quickly (~0.1s). However, when I close the dialog and bring it up again it takes a significantly longer time to show up.

The database and ajax calls are not the problem. The data is appended to the dialog box and I use simple logic to make sure that function isn't called again. Subsequent attempts to open the dialog box *should* be quicker.

Using IE8's profiler I noticed that there are tens of thousands of calls to:

> ```
> "hidden"
> "curCSS"
> "JScript - window script block"
> ```

These function calls don't come up the first time I open the dialog. I'm at a loss for a reason why.

Clearly, there isn't any scripting taking place on the individual elements within the dialog the first time it's loaded, but why would this change on subsequent calls?

Some code:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    closeText: "",
    width: "auto",
    dialogClass: "ddx",
});


$("#button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Check if "this" is empty, if not, data is already loaded
    if ($.trim($("#dialog").html()).length > 0) {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }
    else {

        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#dialog").append(data);

            }
        }); 
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }
}); 
});
```

html in the body:

`<div id="dialog" title="Test Dialog" class="ddx"></div>`

The dialog ends up containing several levels of nested lists with hundreds of li's.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why susequent calls may be slower than the first call is that replacing HTML via ajax is more expensive than adding new code. That is because jquery needs to remove and cleanup old DOM elements before adding new content.

Your first window will probably remain hidden in the DOM after you close it and is replaced the next time a window is opened.

Furthermore jQuery UI has quite a performance impact on large Ajax-Requests, especially in Internet Explorer due to a slow implementation of the cleanData-Method.

[jQueryUI cleanData performance bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9546)

As an example: Replacing 2500 DOM-Elements with jQuery-UI will cost ~600ms in IE8. Without jQueryUI this costs ~200ms.

I have worked around this in my own code by replacing the cleanData-Method and it has speed up my application significantly (see [jsfiddle/cleanData](http://jsfiddle.net/felvhage/r7buw/)). I'm still looking for a jQuery-UI patch, that will work with all jQuery-Versions.

```
//replace this
$.cleanData = function( elems ) {...}
```